# Is a Kähler manifold with fiber $F$ satisying $H^i(F,\mathcal O)=0$ projective?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a Kähler manifold, $B$ a projective manifold, there is a smooth fibration $\pi:X\rightarrow B$, such that all the fibers $F$ of $\pi$ satisfy $H^i(F,\mathcal O)=0,i>0$, then is $X$ a projective manifold?

I know there are some special cases: for example, if all the fibers are projective spaces, Kodaira had proved that the total space must be a projective manifold, but if we relax the condition to $H^i(F,\mathcal O)=0,i>0$, is it still true? This question has already been asked in the comment of [a question in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373297/when-a-fibration-over-a-projective-manifold-is-projective) and Jason Starr commented it is true, but he did not give a proof, and I can't work the proof out by myself, so I ask again here, I need someone to provide more details, thanks!

Comment: Hasn't this been addressed in the comments of [your MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373297/when-a-fibration-over-a-projective-manifold-is-projective)? Jason Starr says "Yes, if the total space is Kaehler and if the fibers are $\mathcal{O}$-acyclic, then the total space is projective."

Comment: @KReiser, yes, you are right, but unfortunately, he only gives the answer but no proof, and what I need is a detailed process because I can't work the details out.

Comment: Your desire for the explanation isn't reflected in your question, though - if you explained "I've been told this and I need some help filling in the details" I think that would make your question a bit better and make it more likely that you receive the help you're looking for.

Comment: @KReiser, thanks, that's what I am doing while you are commenting, I have edited the question as you said.